# Two JLabels copying backgrounds and contents from each other on mouse over

Tags: java, swing, background, jlabel, mouseover

I'm trying to create a mouseOver visual effect for several JLabel elements filled with text. The idea is to make each label darker when mouse enters and then return it to normal when the mouse leaves its area. Also all the labels are placed over a panel that has a background image.

Though simple enough, I've encountered a nasty behavior I can't overcome.

Bug 1: The first time I move mouse over a label it shows me the upper-left corner of my main window as its background.

Bug 2: Then, every time I move mouse over one label once, and then move it over the second label, the second one changes its background to the "summ background" (panel image + semitransparent background) of first label. Above that it seems that even the first label's text contents are being "copied" to the second label's background. This only happened once per label change: if I move mouse over the same label twice, the second mouse over event is painted correctly.

I've already tried to use MouseMotionListener, a different element (JButton), played with component modification methods and eve tried to override paint methods. No result.

I've attached an animated GIF showing the described behavior:
[Two JLabels copying backgrounds and contents from each other](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cPPpd.gif)

I'm relatively new to Swing so I'm not familiar with its caveats. Any idea what might cause this?

Custom Panel class:

```
public class ImagePanel extends JPanel{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3995745756635082049L;

    private Image image = null;

    public ImagePanel(Image image){
        this.image = image;
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if(image != null){
            g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
        }
    }
}
```

MouseListener class:

```
public class MouseHoverPiece implements MouseListener{

private static final Cursor CURSOR_HAND = new Cursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR);
private static final Cursor CURSOR_DEFAULT = new Cursor(Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR);
private static final Color HOVER_SHADOW = new Color(40, 80, 60, 50);

@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    JLabel component = (JLabel)e.getComponent();
    component.setBackground(HOVER_SHADOW);
    component.setCursor(CURSOR_HAND);
    component.setOpaque(true);
    component.repaint();
}

@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    JLabel component = (JLabel)e.getComponent();
    component.setBackground(null);
    component.setCursor(CURSOR_DEFAULT);
    component.setOpaque(false);
    component.repaint();
}
```

MainWindow class:

```
Image background = ResourceLoader.loadImage("board.png");
ImagePanel panel = new ImagePanel(background);
panel.setBounds(10, 55, 480, 480);
panel.setLayout(null);
panel_main.add(panel);

final JLabel lblNewLabel1 = new JLabel("N");
lblNewLabel1.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
lblNewLabel1.setOpaque(false);
lblNewLabel1.setBounds(25, 24, 52, 52);
lblNewLabel1.setFont(lblNewLabel1.getFont().deriveFont(42f));
lblNewLabel1.addMouseListener(new MouseHoverPiece());
panel.add(lblNewLabel1);

final JLabel lblNewLabel2 = new JLabel("O");
lblNewLabel2.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
lblNewLabel2.setOpaque(false);
lblNewLabel2.setBounds(25+52+2, 24, 52, 52);
lblNewLabel2.setFont(lblNewLabel2.getFont().deriveFont(42f));
lblNewLabel2.addMouseListener(new MouseHoverPiece());
panel.add(lblNewLabel2);
```

Comment: Please avoid `setBounds(...)`, usually a sign of newbie code. I'm guessing your image is semi transparent, true?

Comment: What should I use instead of bounds? I just need to force label's size to fixed dimensions. The panel's image and the labels' wrong backgrounds are opaque, while the mouseover background I want to apply is 50% transparent.

Comment: `What should I use instead of bounds?` - you use [layout managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).

Comment: Yep, I tried the GridLayout but had some problems with relative positioning. Will try again, thanks.

Comment: Cross posted: http://www.coderanch.com/t/662090/GUI/java/JLabels-copying-backgrounds-contents-mouse#3075368

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private static final Color HOVER_SHADOW = new Color(40, 80, 60, 50);
```

Swing components have problems with transparent backgrounds because you are breaking the painting rules which state that an opaque component will completely paint the background.

Check out [Backgrounds With Transparency](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/31/backgrounds-with-transparency/) for more information and a couple of solutions to the problem. You can either:

1. do custom painting on the label to manually paint the background
2. use a wrapper component and have that component do the painting for you.

Comment: I've read the mentioned article while investigating my issue. Actully I based some of my code on it. But I think I'm staring to understand the issue ("rules which state that an opaque component will completely paint the background").

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found the solution. Both bugs had disappeared. What I did was to add parent container's (in my case the panel with the board background) repaint:

```
@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    JLabel component = (JLabel)e.getComponent();
    component.setBackground(HOVER_SHADOW);
    component.setCursor(CURSOR_HAND);
    component.setOpaque(true);
    Container container = component.getParent();
    component.repaint();
    container.repaint(); //fix
}

@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    JLabel component = (JLabel)e.getComponent();
    component.setBackground(null);
    component.setCursor(CURSOR_DEFAULT);
    component.setOpaque(false);
    Container container = component.getParent();
    component.repaint();
    container.repaint(); //fix
}
```

Thanks everyone for your help ;)

Comment: There is no need for invoking repaint() on the child component. When you repaint the parent all the children are repainted. This is not really a proper solution. When you change a property of a component, that component is responsible for repainting itself. Your application code should not need to know that the parent must be repainted first.

Comment: Interesting... Though without calling repaint on the parent it doesn't work. I've read in several posts that repaint is needed when changing some specific properties because of faulty Swing implementation. I'm not arguing, just trying to understand the correct way to do things. Seems my 12 years of experience with Java mean nothing when it comes to Swing...

Comment: That fact that you're apply a alpha based color to an opaque component is the cause of your problem, anything else is just a hack which is likely to cause further issues